Identify IC with marking '119 16wwUJG'
I have an HUB 3.0 PCB from a Monitor. The Monitor is OK, but the HUB 3.0 PCB doesn´t work.
Could you help me identify the two ICs U23 and U25?



Based on the way it's wired, I'd say it's most likely an ESD and/or impedance matching array.  The staggered pins might be a clue; most dual row ICs have symmetrical pins on either side.

This chip is an AZ1065-06F from Amazing Microelectronic Corp.
It's an ESD protection array.

Datasheet and picture above can be found here: https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/1388916/AMAZING/AZ1065-06F.R7G.html

Thank you Colin. Yes it is. Thank you to Velvet too. You are great. Thanks and good day
